# Remove all files containing a pattern

Tags: bash, regex

Suppose I have a directory with files and subdirectories underneath it. Some of the files contain a pattern "^File:" in their contents.

Is there some way I can use grep and a bash command to remove files that contain this pattern? Note I am talking about contents of the file, not the filenames.

Comment: This question might be better for unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you could narrow your search by a filename pattern, then you'd get a lot better efficiency from any scripts you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple piped find should suffice (caveat emptor, I haven't tested this against a large set of data -- backup anything important):

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -exec egrep -Il '^File:' {} \;|xargs rm -fv
```

Comment: @Hemm -- Actually I tested mine against files with spaces and it removes them just fine.

You probably want to add -I to your grep or he'll be deleting binary files too.

Comment: @Hemm's example can also potentially run into argument limitations of grep if too many files are matched by the wildcard.

Comment: I tested mine on 100k+ files containing the string with no problems. And I already have -l in it.

Comment: I as in India. `man grep` ;)

Comment: -I- blame sans serif.

Answer (score 4):

```
grep -rlI "meow" * | xargs -I{} rm -v {}
```

The above code removes files containing `meow`.

This also handles cases where there are filenames with spaces and other characters. `xargs rm -f` alone, as suggested in other answers, will fail.

Comment: That doesn't descend into subdirectories.

Comment: Whoops. -r added.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner.

```
grep -r "^File:" /path/to/directory | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq | xargs rm -f
```

Comment: Much more verbose than it needs to be.  Use `grep`'s `-l` option to list just the file names.  The `sort` and `uniq` steps are unnecessary, since the files are just going to be deleted.  `grep -r -l "^File:" /path/to/directory | xargs rm -f`.  Or, if some of the file names might contain funny characters (particularly spaces): `grep -r -l "^File:" /path/to/directory | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 rm -f`.  (I have not tested these; try `xargs echo rm -f` first to make sure it's generating the right list of files.)

Comment: @ChrisTing: Could you provide some explanation about what your code does?

Comment: @KeitThompson: Could you please consider to copy that in an own answer? :)